# Building SVM throws error because my training array has an extra dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am creating a support vector machine. The model below reads the arrays that begin with "log" as vectors in the SVM graph. Arrays log15-log21 are to be classified "c" while the lines log22-log36 are to be classified "d". The goal is to give the svm another vector in the format of the "log" lines and for the svm to label it "c" or "d".

```
from sklearn import svm

log15 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log16 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log17 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log18 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log19 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log20 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
log21 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

log22 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log23 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log24 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log25 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log26 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log27 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log28 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log29 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log30 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log31 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log32 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log33 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log34 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log35 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
log36 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

cLines = [log15, log16, log17, log18, log19, log20, log21]
dLines = [log22, log23, log24, log25, log26, log27, log28, log29, log30, log31, log32, log33, log34, log35, log36]
lines = [log15, log16, log17, log18, log19, log20, log21, log22, log23, log24, log25, log26, log27, log28, log29, log30, log31, log32, log33, log34, log35, log36]

X = [lines]
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  #0 for c, 1 for d
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.predict([[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]))
```

When I run the code above I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/craig/Code/Python Programs/TensorFlowLabs/svm.py", line 34, in <module>
    clf.fit(X, y)
  File "c:\Users\craig\Programming Languages\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py", line 196, in fit
    accept_large_sparse=False,
  File "c:\Users\craig\Programming Languages\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 576, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "c:\Users\craig\Programming Languages\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 968, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator,
  File "c:\Users\craig\Programming Languages\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 788, in check_array
    % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
builtins.ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

An online guide I see does not have the vectors separated by commas, but the individual characters in the vector arrays have significant meaning, so I don't want the 1's and 0's to be "jumbled up", if that makes sense.

Comment: Please do not clutter your posts with stuff irrelevant to the issue itself (who you are, what is your background, what you want to achieve in the future, thanks in advance  etc) - be concise and to the point (edited).

Comment: @desertnaut The information is relevant. I try to keep background information to a minimum, but it is important to know what I am trying to accomplish, and it's not like I wrote 3 full paragraphs explaining the project in detail. I even said "There is a meaning behind the vectors' contents, but I won't confuse you with trivialities".

Comment: I am afraid I cannot see how how many years you have been programming, if this is your first project or your 10th, announcing what you are trying to do before doing something else, and thanking in advance are of any relevance to the *programming* question here; and if you don't believe me, look at the answer!  Please notice that [SO is *not* a (personalized) help desk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/4685471), and the idea of Q&As here is for them to be reusable and helpful for others in the future (probably with completely different backgrounds & end objectives).

Comment: Please notice that being concise and to the point is actually a very real *courtesy* to possible respondents, who do not have to go through a bunch of actually unhelpful material in order to see what is going on and if they can help; in the same sense, "thanks in advance" etc is actually [*not* considered polite here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288179/4685471).

Comment: Re-reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would also be useful: "***Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence: what details can you include that will help someone identify and solve your problem?*". Arguably, not a mini-background about your programming, ML, or project journey, as the answer clearly demonstrates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining X as an array (you are using brackets). That's why you are obtaining an error. Change the way you define X and it should work:

```
X = lines
```